# How to get selected value in select in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select

I want to know how to get the selected value of `<select>`. I only know how to populate this.

Here's is my code in **`index.html.erb`**. I used this to populate the `<select>` dropdown menu.

```
<h1>Trap</h1>

<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
 <p>
  Employee Code: 
  <%= f.select(:empcode_contains, @employee.collect {|e| [ e.empcode,   e.id ]})  %>
 </p>

 <p class="button"><%= f.submit "Search" %></p>
<% end %>

<p>
 Sort by:
 <%= sort_link @search, :empcode %> |
 <%= sort_link @search, :date_entry %> |
</p>

<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Empcode</th>
  <th>Date entry</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>

<% @traps.each do |trap| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= trap.empcode %></td>
  <td><%= trap.date_entry %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', trap %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_trap_path(trap) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', trap, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Trap', new_trap_path %>
```

And in my controller **`traps_controller.rb`**:

```
def index
 @search = Trap.search(params[:search])
 @traps = @search.all
 @employee = Employee.all

 Trap.all.each do |t|
   Employee.create(:empcode => t.empcode)
 end

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @traps }
 end
end
```

Pls tell me how to get the selected value if the user selects a value. I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try (in the controller) :

```
value = params[:empcode_contains]
```

or you could fetch the whole object this way:

```
search = params[:search]
```

Comment: Man, I'm sorry I know my question is not clear and incomplete. Pls check my updated question.

Comment: I don't really understand what has changed in the updated version ?
What do you want to do with the selected value?